# Using returned values from static React function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am trying to do the following in a React + Webpack project with javascript Ecmascript 6 support:

```
class ApiCalls extends React.Component{
  static uploadFiles(files) {
    // upload code
    if(success) {
      return(true, message);
    }
    else {
      return(false, message);
    }
  }
}
export default ApiCalls;
```

Then in my calling component I call the method like this:

```
import ApiCalls from './ApiCalls';
class HomePage extends React.Component {
  ...
  handlePost(files) {
    ApiCalls.uploadFiles(files) = ((success, message) => {
      if (success) {
        console.log('Success! ' + message);
      }
      else {
        console.log('Error! ' + message);
      }
    }
  }
  ...
  render()
  ...
}
export default HomePage;
```

With the above code I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression
```

with arrow pointing to ApiCalls.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are using the `callback function` in a wrong way, pass a function to static function and on success, call that function with parameters, like this:

```
handlePost(files) {
    ApiCalls.uploadFiles(files, (success, message) => {
      if (success) {
        console.log('Success! ' + message);
      }
      else {
        console.log('Error! ' + message);
      }
    })
}
```

Now write the `static function` like this:

```
static uploadFiles(files, target) { //target will be that callback function
    // upload code
    if(success) {
      target(true, message);  //call that function and pass the parameter
    }
    else {
      target(false, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much worked perfectly! Saved me loads of headache. By the way is it bad practice to make a react component like ApiCalls without any render part on it, or is it normal?

Comment: i think, it is a bad practice, if that component doesn't contain any ui part then instead of making it as a `react` component, simply create a file that will have `functions` and export all the function using `module.exports` and call the `functions` according to situation in the same way :)